# Space with complex distance

Tags: metric-spaces

I am interested in a mathematical space with specific properties, but I am not sure if such a space can be consistently defined. I would appreciate any guidance or ideas. If this space is known, what is its name? If this space cannot be defined, then why? If it can be defined, then what would its mathematical definition look like? Finally, if it can exist only in a certain number of dimensions, then what is this number? (Mostly interested in 2 to 4 dimensions).

Target properties:

1. A distance from any point to the chosen unique center of coordinates is a real number (radius-vector).
2. An infinitesimal distance in any direction perpendicular to the radius vector is an imaginary number. (Perhaps better stated this way: the distance between the ends of two radius-vectors of the same length separated by an infinitesimal angle is an imaginary number.)

Example: the circumference of a circle with the radius $R$ and the center in the center of coordinates is $2\pi\cdot R \cdot i $ where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

3. Only one imaginary unit regardless of the number of dimensions (e.g. no quaternions).

***EDIT:** Per the comments below, the following bullet is not well defined or even necesary. Therefore it is here only as a visual illustration of the expected symmetry.*

4. Rotational symmetry in any direction, but only around the center of coordinates.

I need your help to understand if this space is mathematically possible or not. I would appreciate any answers, comments, suggestions, or requests to clarify the question.

---

***EDIT:** Clarifications/updates based on responses. The bullets #2 and #3 above probably should be combined this way (with no imaginary numbers):*

2. The space must be locally asymptotic to a hyperbolic metric space with the following metric:

   $ds^2 = ds_1^2 -ds_2^2$

   where $ds_1$ is the radial coordinate and $ds_2$ is the rotational Euclidian distance (e.g. $ds_2^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are rotational coordinates). Local (infinitesimal) geodesics can be defined in the usual way by the vanishing partial second order derivatives along the geodesic.

   Global geodesics should be segments of logarithmic spirals (including degenerate by either coordinate, such as radius segments or circular segments around the origin). Something like this (see the @pregunton comment below):

   $r = ae^{b\theta}$

   Geodesics may not be unique, but may depend on the number of revolutions around the origin. This is OK and expected.

Comment: how would the triangular inequality work ?

Comment: @mercio: Well, I guess the same way as on the complex plane (using absolute values), unless you mean something else. I don't think it would be a problem locally (over a relatively small area), would it? While I don't see it being a problem globally either, it is not really required to work globally (unless it is mandatory in general). Am I missing your point? Do you have a particular case in mind? This space must be metric locally, but not necessarily globally (such as over areas including the center of coordinates or large angles). If this makes any sense :)

Comment: One thing that I think fulfils your requirements is having the distance between two points in the plane be the complex number whose modulus is the Euclidean length of the unique segment of (possibly degenerate) logarithmic spiral centered at the origin and passing through the two points, and whose argument is the characteristic angle of that logarithmic spiral (i.e., $\arctan(1/b)$ if the spiral's equation is $r=ae^{b\theta}$ in polar coordinates).

Comment: In this way, the distance between two points lying on a circle centered at the origin is the length of the arc of circle (degenerate spiral) joining them multiplied by $i$, and the distance between two points lying on a ray from the origin is the length of the segment connecting them. The distance is evidently invariant under rotations around the origin. You can easily extend this definition to more than two dimensions by taking the unique plane formed by the two points and the origin (the plane is not unique if the points are aligned, but then choosing any plane passing through them works).

Comment: @pregunton: This is interesting, because I already had this spiral defined there for a different reason. The fact that this spiral appears again shows that it relates to the properties of this space. I need to sleep on this, but it looks promising. Meanwhile, would there be any mathematical inconsistency or concern regarding this space?

Comment: @safesphere I can only think of two ambiguities: first, there is actually more than one possible logarithmic spiral passing through two points, but this is not really an issue. The formula for $b$ in terms of the polar coordinates of the two points is $\frac{\log(r_2/r_1)}{\theta_2 - \theta_1}$, and the issue arises because one can add to $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ any integer multiple of $2\pi$. You can solve it by restricting $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$; this corresponds to choosing the "less twisted" spiral passing through the two points.

Comment: In more technical terms, we are choosing a branch of a multivalued function to make it single valued, as it usually happens in the complex world. The second issue concerns the origin. By my definition, the distance between the origin and any other point would be technically indeterminate, because all logarithmic spirals "pass through" the origin. But this can be solved by manually defining the distance to be equal to the usual Euclidean distance in this particular case, without any more inconsistencies arising (that I can think of right now, at least).

Comment: Items 2 and 4 are not defined: What does it mean to be "perpendicular" in your space? What does it mean to be a "rotation" (also, what do you mean by a "direction")? All these notions have precise meaning in an inner product vector space, but you are looking for something else...

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Good points. The meaning of #2 is the distance between the ends of two radius-vectors of the same length separated by a small angle. Would this definition work? I am not sure if #4 is actually required. I just listed it as a visual illustration.So it may not be a definition, but a property resulting from the definitions. I am looking for a space that is locally asymptotic to a metric space with the metric of r^2-x^2 where r points away from the origin and x may be 1 to 3 dimensions (and possibly more) "perpendicular" to the radius vector as described above. Can you please help?

Comment: @safesphere: If you do not know what (4) means you should remove it. As for (2), you should define "small" (to me, this is a meaningless concept). Also, notions of distance usually require some form of triangle inequalities. You seem to skipped this part altogether.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I have edited the question regarding (4). Also, by "small" I simply mean "infinitely small", sorry :)  Wold the following work? "(2) Any distance between the ends of two radius-vectors of the same length at an infinitely small angle is an imaginary number." On triangle inequality, let me ponder it and get back to you later. Thank you!

Comment: The question  now is making even less sense than before. Just go through the text what you wrote and ask yourself "what does it precisely mean". For instance, what does "geodesic mean"? What does "locally asymptotic mean"? What does it mean for a "complex-valued metric to be asymptotic to a semi-Riemannian metric"? My suggestion for your is to pick up a textbook on Riemannian and semi-Riemannian geometry (written by a mathematician, not a physicist) and read 3-4 chapters to get a better grip of the subject.

Comment: @MoisheCohen A good suggestion. Thank you! I will do this. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update makes it much clearer what is wanted for the metric.

Let $d\Theta^2$ denote the spherical metric
(induced by the Euclidean) on $S^{n-1}=\{ x\in {\Bbb R}^n: \|x\|=1\}$ and
write  $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2}$.
The standard Euclidean metric on ${\Bbb R}^n$ may then be written as follows:
$ \sum_i dx_i^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\Theta^2 $.

The central idea in the current post 
is to change the sign on the angular part, i.e. we
consider the punctured Euclidean space
$X={\Bbb R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ equiped 
with the following $(1,n-1)$ pseudo-Riemannian metric:
$$  g= dr^2 - r^2 d\Theta^2 = 
  2 dr^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n dx_i^2$$

We wish to describe geodesics in $(X,g)$. In relativistic terminology,
a tangent vector with $g(v,v)>0$ is time-like,
$g(v,v)<0$ is space-like, while $g(v,v)=0$ corresponds to a
ligth-cone vector.

It is of interest to note that the metric
is invariant under the orthogonal group which implies that there is
angular momentum conservation: A geodesic starting at some
given position in space and in a given direction will always stay in the
span of those two directions, i.e. it suffices to restrict
our attention 
to those two dimensions. So let us write:
 $$ g= dr^2 - r^2 d\phi^2$$
 with $(r,\phi)$ being standard polar coordinates in the plane.

Geodesics in normal Riemannian geometry are paths between
points that are extremal for the length
$\int \sqrt{g(\dot{x},\dot{x})} dt$.
Normalizing to constant speed it
is equivalent to be extremal for the action functional:
$$ S = \int g(\dot{x},\dot{x}) dt  = 
\int {\cal L} (r,\phi,\dot{r},\dot{\phi}) dt,$$
with the Lagrangian ${\cal L} = 
\dot{r}^2 - r^2 \dot{\phi}^2 $.
So we take extremality of this action to define geodesics in the
present context.
An extremal path verifies Lagrange's equations:
$$ 
2 \ddot{r} =
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} =
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = - 2 r \dot{\phi}^2 
 \;\; \mbox{and} \; \;
\frac{d}{dt}  \left( r^2 \dot{\phi} \right) =
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} =
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = 0.
 $$
The last implies the above-mentioned angular conservation: $r^2 \dot{\phi}=A$
for some constant $A$. Similarly, there is conservation of 
energy (Hamiltonian):
$$ E = 
\dot{r}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} +
\dot{\phi} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}} -
L = 2 L - L = L $$
So 
$\dot{r}^2 - r^2 \dot{\phi}^2  = E$ for some constant $E$.

First case: If $\dot{\phi}=0$ at some instant of time then $A=0$ and
$\phi$ is a constant of motion. We may solve to get: $\dot{r}=\pm\sqrt{E}$
which is just a linear motion in time, $r(t) = \pm\sqrt{E}(t-t_0)$
(the geodesic ceases to exist when $r(t_0)=0$).

Second case: When $\dot{\phi}\neq 0$, it has a constant sign
(same as the sign of $A$). We may then by the implicit function theorem
write $r=r(\phi)$  so that $\dot{r} = r'(\phi) \dot{\phi}$. 
Then $(r'^2-r^2) \dot{\phi}^2 = E$ and inserting
the angular momentum conservation we deduce
the following equation for the trajectories:
$$ r'^2 - r^2 = \frac{E}{A^2} r^4$$

Subcases:

a) $E=0$: We get $r'=\pm r$ or $r(\phi) = \exp (\pm (\phi-\phi_0))$.

b) $E<0$ (space-like trajectories): Write $r=1/u$ and solve the resulting ode for $u$. 
  You end up with
  (modulo mistakes in  my calculations):
  $$ r(\phi) = \frac{A/\sqrt{-E}}{\cosh(\phi-\phi_0)} $$

c) $E>0$ (time-like trajectories): 
  $$ r(\phi) = \frac{A/\sqrt{E}}{\sinh(\phi-\phi_0)} $$

Symmetries: A part from the rotational symmetry I don't think that
there are any other. The fact that $(r,\phi)$ is identified
with $(r,\phi+ 2\pi)$ gives a topological constraint which 
prevents us from doing Lorentz-like transformations.

---

My answer to the original post:

A suggestion: In ${\Bbb R}^n$, write $r\cdot r'$ and $|r|$ for the Euclidean scalar product and length, respectively.

Define two infinitesimal (Riemannian) pseudo-metrics between infinitesimal close vectors $r$ and $r+dr$ (with $r\neq 0$):

$$ ds_1 = \left| \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot dr \right|
\; \; {\rm and} \; \;
ds_2 = \left|dr -  \frac{r}{|r|}\left( \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot dr\right) \right|$$
$ds_1$ measures the radial distance, $ds_2$ the rotational. If you want to represent them as complex numbers you may set $dz=ds_1+i ds_2$. Then, $|dz|$ (modulus of complex number) corresponds to the infinitesimal Euclidean distance.

You may then measure "complex" path lengths: If $r(t)$, $t\in [0,1]$ is a $C^1$ curve then
$$  L={\rm len}_{\Bbb C} (r,[0,1]) =  \int_0^1 \left| \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot \dot{r} \right| dt + i  \int_0^1 \left|\dot{r} -  \frac{r}{|r|}\left( \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot \dot{r}\right) \right|dt$$
separates the usual length of the curve into the radial part (real) and the rotational part (imaginary). The modulus of $L$ is equivalent (though not necessarily equal) to the usual Euclidean length of the path.

Depending on your purpose with defining a complex distance, there might be an ambiguity as to the definition of  the distance between two finite vectors $r_1$ and $r_2$ as you would have to specify what a geodesic is in this picture. A perhaps natural choice is to define a geodesic as a path that minimizes Euclidean distances. Then geodesics are straight line segments and the complex distance may be (partially) calculated as follows:

Let $r'$ be the point on the line segment $[r_1;r_2]$  closest to the origin (could be one of the end-points) and let $a\geq 0$ be the distance from the line through $r_1$, $r_2$ and the origin. 
For $0< u\leq v$ write 
$ \Theta(u,v) = u\ln \frac{v+\sqrt{v^2-u^2}}{u} $. Then if $r'$ is not one of the end-points:
$$ d_{\Bbb C}(r_1,r_2) = \left(|r_1|+|r_2|-2|r'| \right)
+  
   i \left(\Theta(a,|r_1|+ \Theta(a,|r_2|)-2\Theta(a,|r'|)\right)$$
while if $r'$ is one of the end-points you get the simpler:
$$ d_{\Bbb C}(r_1,r_2) = \left||r_2|-|r_1|\right|
+  i \; a \left| \ln \frac{|r_2|+\sqrt{|r_2|^2-a^2}}{|r_1|+\sqrt{|r_1|^2-a^2}}\right| $$
separating into how much you move radially and rotationally along the geodesic.
In the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ the imaginary part vanishes as wanted since $r_1$ and $r_2$ are proportional in that case.

Comment: Hi Hans Henrik, thank you so much for working on my problem! Please don't be discouraged by my lack of response. I understand most of the math involved, but I'm not a mathematician, so understanding your solution will take me a bit of time :) To answer your question on the purpose of the complex distance, this space must be locally asymptotic with the metric space of the hyperbolic metric $ds_1^2 - ds_2^2$ where $ds_1$ is asymptotic to the radial coordinate and $ds_2$ is asymptotic to the angular linear coordinate. I'm a bit over my head here, please let me know if this makes no sense :)

Comment: Accordingly, local (asymptotic or infinitely small, whichever is the appropriate term) geodesics perhaps should be defined by the vanishing partial second derivatives along the geodesic. Globally geodesic are probably logarithmic spirals (including degenerate by either coordinate). This is what I thought and also mentioned by pregunton in the comments, but please do not hesitate to correct, if this seems wrong. This way a geodesic may not be unique, but may depend on the number of revolutions around the origin. This is OK and expected, unless it creates a logical inconsistency.

Comment: Clarification: By "angular linear" I meant "rotational". Please excuse my lack of familiarity with the conventional terminology :)

Comment: Ok, at least that gives more sense to the question. I don't have the time right now but will try to get back to this later on. You should perhaps write some more details regarding this in your question. It looks like seeking geodesics (or rather stationary paths) for the integral of ${\rm Re}\; dz^2$. In fact the representation as complex numbers is irrelevant.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! I have updated the question as requested.

Comment: I follow you. Sorry for the troubles with the straight line :) Let us define geodesics as $r_2 = r_1e^{b\phi}$ where $\phi$ is the angle between $r_1$ and $r_2$ and $b = \tan(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a constant angle between $r$ and the geodesic. Then the radial component of the distance is as in your last equation $R = ||r_2| - |r_1||$ and the rotational distance is $D = bR$ where $b = \ln(r_2/r_1) / \phi$ except for $R = 0$ we get $D = r\phi$ Does this all seem correct? Geodesics must be unique for each number of revolutions around the origin, but this probably holds.

Comment: I'll soon make an update. Given your last explanation which puts a lot of sense into the question there are a lot of things that can be said. You are dealing with a pseudo-Riemannian metric (of signature $(1,n-1)$) corresponding to the usual relativistic space-time metric $c^2dt^2- (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$ but in rather different coordinates. More to come ...

Comment: I'll be very grateful! Please take your time, there's no urgency at all :) My main concern is if the hyperbolic space can be defined this way in polar coordinates. For example, if locally (where the metric is asymptotic to $ds_1^2 - ds_2^2$) I do a hyperbolic rotation of coordinates, then what would it look like globally? I don't mean to derive the formulas, I only wonder if this would create any logical inconsistency on a larger scale. (Also, in the last metric, please feel free to keep $c$ or set $c=1$ for simplicity as you prefer.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is the most help I've ever gotten :) In case I have a quick question on these formulas, may I email you directly at psud?

Comment: Yes, that is fine with me.